# Required field - How to ensure that users entered

Tags: administration

I want to ensure that users complete the field (`Desc`) when creating a new record so I have set the `Desc` as required on that object but some users are still able to create a new record without entering the required field (`Desc`)

What should I check to make sure its required for all the users?

Comment: I double check that in my page layout the `Desc` is required

Comment: Making it mandatory on the page layout is not the same thing as making it required on the custom object.

Answer (score 1):

Goto your custom object --> fields --> Desc -->

click on Desc and click on edit --> checked the required checkbox --> save.

Now it will be required  for all users